# How to track memory assign by STL library

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, std, c++14

I want to track all the memory(size allocated by std lib) allocated by all STL containers like map,list,vector etc. I just want to track STL container not regular object creation. Basically want to override new and delete of std lib.

Example

```
class demo  {
public:
  int i;
  std::list<int> mylist;
}

int main() {
demo dd = new demo(); // -> Don't want to track this. Just want to track
                      //    mylist(size of my list) 
}
```

I found out that std has it's own allocator option. For example list has it is allocator

```
template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class list;
```

What is the default allocator if I don't defined anything. I have thousand of list and none of then has allocator and I don't want to change each one of them manually. So, what I was thinking if there is way where I can replace default allocator with mine.

How to do this ?

Comment: Define track memory?

Comment: @iharob can you elaborate with example ?

Comment: I? you have to elaborate, what you want to do apparently makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I see why my  comment is confusing, I am asking you to define what you mean with _track memory_.

Comment: @iharob edited the question. I hope now it's clear

Comment: "if there is way where I can replace default allocator with mine."  You can use a simple `using` declaration. `template<typename T> using my_list<T> = std::list<T,MyAllocator<T>>; `   Every time you use a `my_list` it will have your own allocator.

Comment: @Alejandro I don't know whether I understand your reply or not. my_list is just an example so there are many list's with different name. I want all list to use my allocator. Can you give me small example

Comment: @eswaat I understand that you will have many different `my_list` instances, each with different names, but the using declaration I gave above ( which actually is a tad off, but I can't edit it) would solve the problem for you, at least partially. Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7222d262e57f1de0)

Comment: While this may be an interesting exercise for research purposes, if you are instead trying to solve an actual problem, you may want to take a look at something like "jemalloc" or "tcmalloc" (part of google's open source "gperftools" https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/)

Comment: @kfsone I am already using tcmalloc library.

Answer (score 2):

The default allocator for the standard containers is [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), it is used for all standard containers (`std::vector`, `std::list`, etc) when an allocator is not provided.

To track allocations and deallocations you will have to create an allocator that you can use for tracking. You could use something like this:

```
template<typename _Ty>
struct MyAllocator
{
    typedef _Ty value_type;
    static _Ty* allocate(std::size_t n) 
    {    
        //Code that runs every allocation
        ...
        return std::allocator<_Ty>{}.allocate(n); 
    }

    static void deallocate(_Ty* mem, std::size_t n)
    {
        //Code that runs every deallocation
        ...
        std::allocator<_Ty>{}.deallocate(mem, n);
    }
};
```

`MyAllocator` mirrors `std::allocator` but it allows you to run some of your own code when an allocation occurs. What you want to put there is up to you.

There are two ways for you to make all of the containers use your allocator.

1. You can replace all instances of `std::list` (or `std::vector`, `std::map`, etc.) with a template alias. For `std::list` the alias would look like this:

   ```
   template<typename _Ty>
   using MyList = std::list<_Ty, MyAllocator<_Ty>;
   ```

   Replace all instances of `std::list` with `MyList`. Now your allocator is used by all of your containers. To apply this to another container change `list` to the name of the container (Ex. for `vector` rename the alias to `MyVector` and change `std::list` to `std::vector`).
2. If you are unable to edit the file or you don't want to modify it there is another option. You can use a macro to replace all instances of `list` with a class you have defined. This class will have to have been declared in `namespace std` and you will have to make sure to include `<list>` before setting up the macro. Setting it up for `std::list` would look like this:

   ```
   #include <list>

   namespace std
   {
       template<typename _Ty, typename _Alloc = MyAllocator<_Ty>>
       using tracked_list = list<_Ty, _Alloc>;
   }

   #define list tracked_list
   ```

   For a different container, change `list` to whatever container you want to replace (Ex. for `vector` change `tracked_list` to `tracked_vector` in both locations and replace `list` with `vector` in all three locations. Make sure that this code is before any other includes that could use `std::list`. If you put it in a header file, include that header before anything else. If it is in a source file, put it at the top of the file. This code will not override user supplied allocators, but it will make your allocator the default allocator.

   This method will change variable names, and that could affect your code. If possible, you should use method 1. However, if you have code that you can't change or code that is in external headers and this needs to be applied to that too, this method should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your main priority is short term low implementation cost (as opposed to longer term maintainability), one way to get around it is to wrap your `demo` class into an `outer` namespace that contains a `std` namespace. Inside `outer::std` you can redefine `vector`, `list`, etc. with your custom allocator. By doing so, all references to the `std` namespace will resolve to `outer::std`.
The only work needed (in addition to implementing your custom allocator) is to wrap all your code into the outer namespace and to provide all the required definitions in `outer::std`. That part might easily become a pain. Future contributors might suffer.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
namespace outside
{
    template<typename T>
    struct MyAllocator
    {
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::const_pointer const_pointer;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::reference reference;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::size_type size_type;
    pointer allocate (size_type n, typename std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint=0)
    {
        std::cerr << "allocate..." << std::endl;
        return std::allocator<T>{}.allocate(n, hint);
    }
    void deallocate (pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        std::cerr << "deallocate..." << std::endl;
        return std::allocator<T>{}.deallocate(p, n);
    }
    template <class Type> struct rebind
    {
        typedef MyAllocator<Type> other;
    };
    MyAllocator()
    {
    }
    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<T>& other )
    {
    }
    template< class U >
    MyAllocator( const MyAllocator<U>& other )
    {
    }
};
} // namespace outside

namespace outer
{
namespace std
{
template<class T>
using vector = ::std::vector<T, outside::MyAllocator<T>>;
} // namespace std

class demo
{
public:
    int i;
    std::vector<int> myVector;
};
} // namespace outer

int main()
{
    using outer::demo;
    std::cerr << "creating new demo" << std::endl;
    demo *dd = new demo();
    std::cerr << "resizing dd->myList" << std::endl;
    dd->myVector.resize(10,3);
    delete dd;
}
```

Comment: Would just like to add that newer versions of gcc and clang permit you to write a "minimal" allocator, without the need for all the typedefs and some other verbiage,  albeit their implementations a bit flawed ( such as with std::list )

Comment: you miss one curly bracket to complete outer namespace.

Comment: I created the same thing for deque but somehow it's not working    template<class T>
using deque = ::std::deque<T, outside::MyAllocator<T>>;

Comment: @eswaat I have added the missing constructors to get it to work with deque and other non-contiguous storage as well. You'll need to customize them for your needs.

Comment: I think it's unsafe to return an allocation from a temporary allocator

Comment: @Dani why would it be unsafe to return an allocation from a temporary allocator?

Comment: @ComeRaczy: The allocator can choose to free all allocations when it is destructed.

Comment: If you're already using tcmalloc, it already provides a heap profiler and checker, and all of the stl allocations should be going through tcmalloc for you already, so you should be able to leverage it to help you do this. https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/wiki/GooglePerformanceTools

Comment: @Dani If the std::allocator frees all allocations when it is destructed, wouldn't that contradict that two std::allocator are always equal and therefore that storage allocated from any std::allocator can be deallocated via any other std::allocator?