# Error while copying one vector to other c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, stl, operator-overloading

I have overloaded allocator for most of the stl containers below is the code. The code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471582/how-to-track-memory-assign-by-stl-library)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

namespace outside
{
    template<typename T>
    struct MyAllocator
    {
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::const_pointer const_pointer;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::reference reference;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::size_type size_type;
    pointer allocate (size_type n, typename std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint=0)
    {
        std::cerr << "allocate..." << std::endl;
        return std::allocator<T>{}.allocate(n, hint);
    }
    void deallocate (pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        std::cerr << "deallocate..." << std::endl;
        return std::allocator<T>{}.deallocate(p, n);
    }
    template <class Type> struct rebind
    {
        typedef MyAllocator<Type> other;
    };
    MyAllocator()
    {
    }
    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<T>& other )
    {
    }
    template< class U >
    MyAllocator( const MyAllocator<U>& other )
    {
    }
};
} // namespace outside

namespace outer
{
template<class T>
using vector = ::std::vector<T, outside::MyAllocator<T>>;

template<class T>
using list = ::std::list<T, outside::MyAllocator<T>>;
}


int main()
{
    outer::vector<int> myVector1;
    outer::vector<int> myVector2;
    myVector1.push_back(10);
    myVector1.push_back(20);
    // myVector2 = myVector1; // Getting compilation error
    for (auto i = myVector1.begin(); i != myVector1.end(); ++i) {
       std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }

    std::list<int> myList1;
    std::list<int> myList2;
    myList2 = myList1; // // No compilation error
}
```

Copying one vector to another vector is giving me error. While for the same code copying one list to another list is working fine.

Compilation error

```
included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc: In instantiation of 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = outside::MyAllocator<int>]':
prog.cpp:59:15:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' and 'const _Tp_alloc_type {aka const outside::MyAllocator<int>}')
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iosfwd:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/postypes.h:221:5: note: candidate: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator!=(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator!=(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/postypes.h:221:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::fpos<_StateT>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:227:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:227:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:304:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:304:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:354:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:354:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:1077:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator!=(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator!=(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:1077:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:1083:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator!=(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator!=(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:1083:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:140:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator!=(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
     operator!=(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:140:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::allocator<_CharT>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:146:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator!=(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_CharT>&)
     operator!=(const allocator<_Tp>&, const allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:146:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::allocator<_CharT>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4948:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4948:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4960:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4960:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'outside::MyAllocator<int>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4972:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
     operator!=(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4972:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:46:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/system_error:311:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator!=(const std::error_code&, const std::error_code&)
   operator!=(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
   ^
/usr/include/c++/5/system_error:311:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' to 'const std::error_code&'
/usr/include/c++/5/system_error:315:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator!=(const std::error_code&, const std::error_condition&)
   operator!=(const error_code& __lhs, const error_condition& __rhs) noexcept
   ^
/usr/include/c++/5/system_error:315:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' to 'const std::error_code&'
/usr/include/c++/5/system_error:319:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator!=(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_code&)
   operator!=(const error_condition& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
   ^
/usr/include/c++/5/system_error:319:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' to 'const std::error_condition&'
/usr/include/c++/5/system_error:323:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator!=(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_condition&)
   operator!=(const error_condition& __lhs,
   ^
/usr/include/c++/5/system_error:323:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' to 'const std::error_condition&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_facets.h:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:210:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator!=(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
     operator!=(const istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>& __a,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:210:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:1535:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:1535:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/list:63:0,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:291:5: note: candidate: template<class _Val> bool std::operator!=(const std::_List_iterator<_Tp>&, const std::_List_const_iterator<_Val>&)
     operator!=(const _List_iterator<_Val>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:291:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::_List_iterator<_Tp>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/list:63:0,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:1843:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const list<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const list<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:1843:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
```

I am trying to understand why this is the case and solution for this problem ?

Comment: @Galik: Did you uncomment the line that says "getting compilation error"?

Comment: @DieterLücking updated post with compilation error.

Comment: @MooingDuck lol good point!

Comment: It looks like you need to implement `operator!=` in your allocator class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of the exception is hundreds of lines into it:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/vector:64:0,
             from main.cpp:2:    /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1535:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator!=(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1535:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/vector:69:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:176:37: note:   'std::_Vector_base<int, outside::MyAllocator<int> >::_Tp_alloc_type {aka outside::MyAllocator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>'
            && _M_get_Tp_allocator() != __x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
                                     ^
```

`vector::operator=` requires `vector::operator!=`, which requires `allocator::operator!=`, which doesn't exist.  Without it, the function can't be created.  Simply add an `operator!=` to your allocator.  While you're at it, also make sure you have all the other required allocator functions.  If memory serves me right, you're missing a fair number.

Comment: Construct/desctruct to begin with, yes.

Comment: like this template<class U> MyAllocator& operator !=(const MyAllocator<U> &) { return *this;}

Comment: @eswaat: ... No.  `operator!=` is a boolean operator.  `template<class U> bool operator !=(const MyAllocator<U> &) { return false;}`.  You'll probably need `operator==` which should probably return true.  (All your allocators are equal, because they're 100% identical)

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks. I think you are right http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/operator_cmp  .Since default allocators are stateless, two default allocators are always equal. So operator != will always return false and operator == will always return true. I am understanding right ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition to `struct MyAllocator: public std::allocator<T>` and the code will compile.